# Absolute uncertainity in weight

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, error-analysis, weight

An object has a mass of 88.60 kg ± 0.09 kg. I calculated the weight to be 869 N 
but now I need to calculate the absolute uncertainty in weight.

My thinking was that the absolute uncertainty would be .09/869 = 0.0001. Then multiply that by the weight, so .0001 by 869. So 0.09 but however this is not correct Looking for some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight is given by:

$$ W = mg $$

where $m$ is your mass and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. If we have some error in the mass we can write the mass as $m \pm \sigma_m$ where $\sigma_m$ is the error (0.09 kg in this case) so we get:

$$\begin{align}
 W &= (m \pm \sigma_m)g \\
   &= mg \pm \sigma_mg
\end{align}$$

So the weight we get is $mg$ with an error of $\pm \sigma_mg$.

(This is assuming we can ignore any errors in the value of $g$.)

Comment: so how do I calculate +- Og  sorry didn't know how to do the symbol

Comment: so .09 * 9.8 ????

Comment: and would the unit be Newtons then?

Comment: @javahelper123: you can see the code used to generate symbols by right clicking on the symbol and choosing *Show math as* then *TeX commands* on the popup menu.

Comment: thanks for that  so would .09 * 9.8 = .9N be the correct answer?

Comment: @javahelper123: Yes